# How to set gdb as debugger for the C/C++ extension pf VSCode on MacOS?

Tags: c++, macos, visual-studio-code, gdb, vscode-debugger

the C/C++ Extension of Microsoft for VSCode allows to set a `launch.json` file with which you can set how to debug and run your C++ code. By default it has lldb as debugger for MacOS.

I wonder how to set gdb as debugger instead of lldb.

I tried and it shows me:

> Unable to start debugging. GDB exited unexpectedly with exit code 134 (0x86).

This is how my `launch.json` file looks like:

```js
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "g++-9 - Build and debug active file",
            "type": "cppdbg",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${fileDirname}/${fileBasenameNoExtension}",
            "args": [],
            "stopAtEntry": false,
            "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
            "environment": [],
            "externalConsole": true,
            "osx": {
                "miDebuggerPath": "/usr/local/bin/gdb",
                "MIMode": "gdb"
            },
            
            "preLaunchTask": "C/C++: g++-9 build active file"
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Make sure you have **gdb** installed.
For that you can use:

```
brew install gdb
```

Then make the **gdb** binary is certified. Because:

> ... modern Darwin kernels restrict the capability to assume
> control over another process (here, for the purpose of debugging it),
> since that capability is a boon to malware. In order for said
> taskgated to grant access to gdb, the latter must be fitted with
> entitlements, which consist of digitally-signed metadata inside the
> gdb binary.

From: https://sourceware.org/gdb/wiki/PermissionsDarwin

To create a certification follow these instructions:
https://sourceware.org/gdb/wiki/PermissionsDarwin

After doing so, certify the binary as instructed [here](https://sourceware.org/gdb/wiki/PermissionsDarwin).

Then try this for `launch.json`:

```
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "g++ - Build and debug active file",
            "type": "cppdbg",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${fileDirname}/${fileBasenameNoExtension}",
            "args": [],
            "stopAtEntry": false,
            "cwd": "${fileDirname}",
            "environment": [],
            "externalConsole": false,
            "MIMode": "gdb",
            "preLaunchTask": "C/C++: g++ build active file"
        }
    ]
 }
```